# pg-promise, format with json-object

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

From pg-promise's example, one can format a query like below, where ${this~} becomes all of the keys in the object that is the second parameter of "format()".

```
// automatically list object properties as sql names:
format('INSERT INTO table(${this~}) VALUES(${one}, ${two})', {
    one: 1,
    two: 2
});
//=> INSERT INTO table("one","two") VALUES(1, 2)
```

Is it possible to also get all of the values of the object, without explicitly typing all of them? I want to do it like below (should do the same thing as the snippet above, but without typing all of the values):

```
format('INSERT INTO table(${this~}) VALUES(${this#})', {
    one: 1,
    two: 2
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to also get all of the values of the object, without explicitly typing all of them?

No, it is not possible, because while column names require the same-type SQL Name escaping, values do not, they require templating that's possible only via explicitly defined variables.

> I want to do it like below...

For that you should use the [helpers](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) methods of the library:

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['one', 'two'], {table: 'my-table'});
const query = pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs);
```